# iOS and Android links to foursquare lists

Tags: list, foursquare

There's a way to create links which point directly into the native foursquare application: https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/client

But it seems there are no such kind of links for lists. Is it possible to create a link which opens some foursquare list in the app, not in browser?

Answer (score 0):

There are no native deeplinks for foursquare lists at this time.